# Vue3 doesn't seem to be loaded in Rails 7 + shakapacker app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, shakapacker

I created a new project for a shopify app with rails 7 and shakapacker. I want to use Vue components in my .slim files. The problem is that Vue doesn't seem to be loaded in my app, although I don't get any errors.

Here is what I did:

```js
// config/webpack/rules/vue.js

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.vue'
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
// config/webpack/webpack.config.js

const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('shakapacker')
const vueConfig = require('./rules/vue')

module.exports = merge(vueConfig, webpackConfig)
```

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import HelloWorld from '../components/HelloWorld'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp({
  el: '#app'
})

app.component('helloworld', HelloWorld)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  app
})
```

```js
// app/javascript/components/HelloWorld.vue

<template>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld'
}
</script>
```

```
/ app/views/layouts/embedded_app.slim

doctype html
html[lang="en"]
  head
    meta[charset="utf-8"]
    - application_name = ShopifyApp.configuration.application_name
    title
      = application_name
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload"
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  body
    #app
      .wrapper
        main[role="main"]
          = yield

    = content_tag(:div, nil, id: 'shopify-app-init', data: { api_key: ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key,
        shop_origin: @shop_origin || (@current_shopify_session.shop if @current_shopify_session),
        host: @host,
        debug: Rails.env.development? })
```

And finally, the view where I just want to display the `HelloWorld.vue` component:

```
/ app/views/home/index.slim

helloworld
```

However, nothing is displayed and I have no errors. I tried to modify the creation of the app in this way, to see if the log appears:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import HelloWorld from '../components/HelloWorld'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp({
  el: '#app',
  created () {
    console.log('ok')
  }
})

app.component('helloworld', HelloWorld)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  app
})
```

but then again, I have nothing in console, so I'm not even sure that the app is well rendered. On the other hand, I checked that the `DOMContentLoaded` event is indeed triggered and it is.

I'm not very comfortable with webpack so I don't know if something is wrong with my configuration, I followed shakapacker's README.

I don't think this is related, but the app is rendered in a Shopify test store via an Ngrok tunnel.

I don't know where to look anymore... Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't written any VueJS in a long time, but this is usually what I do in my application.js using React & Shopify Polaris components.

```
function initialize() {
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('app')
  const root = createRoot(rootElement);

  /* some app bridge code I removed here */

  /* react 18 */
  root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      /* ... */
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

document.readyState !== 'loading' ?  initialize() : document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => initialize())
```

If your `<div id="app">` is EMPTY when inspected with browser tools, my first guess would be you're creating an instance, but not actually rendering it in the end.

> An application instance won't render anything until its .mount() method is called.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app

*I would've commented to ask first, but I don't have enough reputation points to do so*

Comment: The reason for the code snippet above is to illustration how root object initialization comes in 2 steps; createRoot(), then root.render().

Your VueJS code shows createApp(), and I assumed you're missing some "mount" or "render" method to follow.

Comment: Thanks @bashr, you were right, I forgot the root component then app.mount('#app')... It wasn't a good day for coding. 